# xcode - Add AVFountation Framework

Tags: iphone, xcode, avfoundation

I'm creating an iphone app using xcode 4.2, and trying to use the AVFoundation Framework to play some radio stream.
When i import it to the project's frameworks and the build, i get the following warning:

`ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/xanthos/Documents/tabbartest/AVFoundation.framework/AVFoundation, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (i386)`

and of course when using anything of the framework (eg AVAudioSession) i get errors like:

`Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AVAudioSession", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in RadioStreamer.o`

I've read so many posts about how to compile AVFoundation Library, by i really don't get it, i'm really inexperienced in all these. I can see there's something with the linking of the library, but not completely understand it.

Any clues please?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It looks like you have you copied `AVFoundation.framework` from somewhere to your project directory. That's wrong. You just need to add it to the "Link Binary With Libraries" build phase of your project:

1. In Xcode, select the project in the navigator on the left.
2. Select the 'Build phases' tab in the main area in the middle.
3. Open up the 'Link Binary With Libraries' section.
4. Click the '+'.
5. Select `AVFoundation.framework. and click 'Add'.

Comment: +1000 matt! Thanks a lot! that was it, learned my lesson today :)
Thanks again!