# I would like to play a sound when I tap on an image then go to another page

Tags: image, audio, swift3

I would like to play any sound when a the first image is tapped and then go to the second image page. 
[This is the storyboard image of the specific part where I want the code to be based off of.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BDdKf.png)
can someone please help me.
how do I add this code into my code 
other code. code someone gave to help me:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController , UIGestureRecognizerDelegate
{

@IBOutlet weak var imgPhoto: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad()
{


    super.viewDidLoad()
    let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(playSound(tapGestureRecognizer:)))
    imgPhoto.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    imgPhoto.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer) /*Adding Gesture to image*/
}

/*
 This method is called when user tap on gesture and sound is played
 */
func playSound(tapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer)
{

    print("play")
        guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource:"a", withExtension: "mp3") else { return }
        do
        {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)

            /*
             This method is used to notify when audio is completed
             */
           NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.soundPlayComplete(sender:)), name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: url)

            player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
            guard let player = player else { return }
            player.prepareToPlay()
            player.play()
            print("hhh")
        } catch let error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }

}

func soundPlayComplete(sender: Notification) {
    print("Complete")
    //After completion audio you can perform segue here
}

}
```

My code I want the other code to be added into.

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var touchImageView: UIImageView!
}


let soundFilenames = ["5","8","7","4","6","1","3","2"]
var audioPlayers = [AVAudioPlayer]()
var lastAudioPlayer = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()



    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    // Set up audio players
    for sound in soundFilenames {

        do {

            let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: sound, ofType: "wav")!)
            let audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer (contentsOf:url)

            audioPlayers.append(audioPlayer)
        }
        catch {

                       audioPlayers.append(AVAudioPlayer())
        }
               }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

    // Get the audioPlayer that corresponds to the button that they tapped
    let lastPlayer = audioPlayers[lastAudioPlayer]
    lastPlayer.stop();
    lastAudioPlayer = sender.tag;
    lastPlayer.currentTime = 0;
    let audioPlayer = audioPlayers[sender.tag]
    audioPlayer.currentTime=0;
    audioPlayer.play();
}

@IBAction func tbuttonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

    // Get the audioPlayer that corresponds to the button that they tapped

    let lastPlayer = audioPlayers[lastAudioPlayer]
    lastPlayer.stop();
    lastAudioPlayer = sender.tag;
    lastPlayer.currentTime = 0;
    let audioPlayer = audioPlayers[sender.tag]
    audioPlayer.currentTime=0;
    audioPlayer.play()

}

}
```

Comment: I give my credits for helping me in the code to

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/6028575/jaydeep-vyas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you Need to import AVFoundation to play sound (Also dont forget to add in  project https://stackoverflow.com/a/9864504/6028575)

```
 import UIKit
    import AVFoundation

    class ViewController: UIViewController , UIGestureRecognizerDelegate
    {

var player: AVAudioPlayer?

          @IBOutlet weak var touchImageView: UIImageView!

        override func viewDidLoad()
        {


            super.viewDidLoad()
            let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(playSound(tapGestureRecognizer:)))
            touchImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            touchImageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer) /*Adding Gesture to image*/
        }

        /*
         This method is called when user tap on gesture and sound is played
         */
        func playSound(tapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer)
        {

            print("play")
                guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource:"1", withExtension: "mp3") else { return }
                do
                {
                    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
                    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)

                    /*
                     This method is used to notify when audio is completed
                     */
                   NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.soundPlayComplete(sender:)), name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: url)

                    player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
                    guard let player = player else { return }
                    player.prepareToPlay()
                    player.play()
                    print("hhh")
                } catch let error {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }

        }

        func soundPlayComplete(sender: Notification) {
            print("Complete")
            //After completion audio you can perform segue here
        }

    }
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151205/discussion-on-answer-by-jaydeep-vyas-i-would-like-to-play-a-sound-when-i-tap-on).

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the tap gesture on your `imageView` and then use [AVAudioPlayer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudioplayer) to play the sound after that implement the [delegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudioplayerdelegate) method of `AVAudioPlayer` which will invoke once your sound finished playing and then open the another `view controller using perform segue or using Bundle`

Comment: how do you implement the delegate method of AVAudioPlayer and then open the another view controller using perform segue or using Bundle?

Comment: You need to first conform the protocol AVAudioPlayerDelegate on yourView controller or your other class and then set audioplayer.delegate= self and after this implement the method  func audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying(_ player: AVAudioPlayer, 
                             successfully flag: Bool) which will call automatically.

Comment: I am a begginner

Comment: we can chat on messenger on Facebook so you could help me in a chat and I could send images and videos to you so you can have an easier time helping me code

Comment: @Jared miller, which part you did not understand?

Comment: You need to first conform the protocol AVAudioPlayerDelegate on yourView controller or your other class and then set audioplayer.delegate= self and after this implement the method func audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying(_ player: AVAudioPlayer, successfully flag: Bool) which will call automatically. and You need to set the tap gesture on your imageView and then use AVAudioPlayer to play the sound after that implement the delegate method of AVAudioPlayer which will invoke once your sound finished playing and then open the another view controller using perform segue or using Bundle

Comment: we can chat on messenger on Facebook so you could help me in a chat and I could send images and videos to you so you can have an easier time helping me code

Comment: can we chat on facebook

Comment: so you can help me please

Comment: @JaredMiller, Your code looks good only where you are facing the issue now?

Comment: If your method(soundPlayComplete) is calling then you just need to open the view controller.

Comment: This is the only last part which is pending from your end

Comment: And sorry I do not use the messanger., you can email me your code if your code if you would like?(er.hussain52@gmail.com)